# Why can't I rotate the view?

Tags: 3d-view

[image: screenshot of Blender: some circle shows up when I try to rotate a cube]

I don't know any shortcut, and I can't rotate the view anymore. If I rotate, some circle shows up. Previously, before I couldn't rotate anymore, the circle did not show up. I tried reinstalling the software and it still happens.

Edit: I'm sorry, I had problems with my middle mouse button, which didn't work correctly anymore. I changed the mouse and now it's working.

Comment: You are not rotating the view, you are rotating an object and you seem to have proportional editing turned on.

Comment: if i rotate view its cant rotate, can help me?? i do load factory setting, and its works, but cant rotate view again, its some bug??

Answer (score 2):

That circle appears when you are using proportional editing. You can't edit and rotate or navigate at the same time. One you are done executing whatever transformation you are doing, then you will be able to navigate.

A way to exit the tools in blender is by pressing the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

The same applies when you are using circle select (keyboard shortcut <kbd>C</kbd>), box select or lasso select. Selection tools will not let you rotate until you are done selecting. Press escape to exit selection and then navigate in the viewport.